# Using dynamic SQL in stored procedure?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm creating a stored procedure for MySQL in a C# app.  The stored procedure contains some dynamically created SQL used to drop an index if it exists, then [re]create it.  The SQL code works fine in MySQL Workbench, but when I run it from my C# app, I'm getting a MySQL Exception.

Here's the stored procedure code (as it is used in C#, there are no "@" symbols before identifiers as C# puts them in itself, as I understand it):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE recreate_index_sp(IN theTable varchar(128), IN theIndexName varchar(128), IN theIndexColumns varchar(128)) 
BEGIN 
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS index_exists FROM information_schema.statistics WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() and table_name = theTable AND index_name = theIndexName) > 0) THEN 
        SET s = CONCAT( 'DROP INDEX ', theIndexName, ' ON ', theTable );
        PREPARE stmt FROM s;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END IF;
    SET s = CONCAT('CREATE INDEX ' , theIndexName , ' ON ' , theTable, '(', theIndexColumns, ')');
    PREPARE stmt FROM s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

The exception I'm getting is: `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unknown system variable 's'`.

If I therefore define `s` at the start of the stored procedure - `DECLARE s varchar(255)` - I instead get the error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's;EXECUTE stmt;DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;END' at line 1`.  But the code I use in MySQL Workbench doesn't need to define the variable, so I don't know why it's insisting on it here.

If I use `@s` as the variable name instead (including defining it!), the exception says `Parameter '@s' must be defined`.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

For info, here is the code I use in MySQL Workbench that creates the procedure quite happily:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE recreate_index_sp(IN theTable varchar(128), IN theIndexName varchar(128), IN theIndexColumns varchar(128))
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS index_exists FROM information_schema.statistics WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() and table_name = @theTable AND index_name = @theIndexName) > 0) THEN
        SET @s = CONCAT( 'DROP INDEX ', @theIndexName, ' ON ', @theTable );
        PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END IF;
    SET @s = CONCAT('CREATE INDEX ', @theIndexName, ' ON ', @theTable, '(', @theIndexColumns, ')');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

---

**EDIT**: Thanks to Reubz, I got the code working.  Two parts were needed: (1) The connection string needed "Allow User Variables=True;" including, and (2) the @ symbol was required (and the variable did not need declaring).

So here's the working code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE recreate_index_sp(IN theTable varchar(128), IN theIndexName varchar(128), IN theIndexColumns varchar(128)) 
BEGIN 
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS index_exists FROM information_schema.statistics WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() and table_name = theTable AND index_name = theIndexName) > 0) THEN 
        SET @sqlPrep = CONCAT( 'DROP INDEX ', theIndexName, ' ON ', theTable );
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlPrep;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END IF;
    SET @sqlPrep = CONCAT('CREATE INDEX ' , theIndexName , ' ON ' , theTable, '(', theIndexColumns, ')');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlPrep;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

Comment: If it makes any difference, I'm using MySQL Connector Net v6.5.5, MySQL Server v5.1, and coding the C# app in Visual Studio 2012 Pro.

Comment: How are you creating this stored proc in c#? Can you post the actual code?

Comment: It's fairly hard to post the code as it's wrapped up in inumerable class objects, but suffice to say: I can create other stored procedures, tables and views using the exact same code, so I don't think it's the C# code itself.  But I'll see what I can extract.

Comment: Ok, just trying to understand how the stored proc is created. are you passing this stored proc as a string? Then you'd need to supply the @ symbol for all your variables, not just the s variable.

Comment: Ok, it's using Reflection to load the MySql .NET dll; the command is executed using a MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand object, calling ExecuteNonQuery().  Works for all other stored procedures I'm creating, just not this one.

Comment: Yes, it's as a string (setting the CommandText property of the MySqlCommand object).  If I pass @ symbol for my other stored procedures, they all fail.  But I'll try with this one to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Tried that - gives the exception message `parameter @theTable must be defined` - i.e. it complains about the very first parameter I use.

Comment: ok, at the start of the stored proc, instead of saying DEFINE s, try DECLARE s varchar(255)

Comment: Whoops, that was a mistype in my question - I was actually using DECLARE.  Will correct the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35586/discussion-between-nick-shaw-and-reubz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our chat:

you have to use the @ symbol for your user defined variable s, in order to differentiate it from a system variable. However, user defined variables are disabled by default in newer versions of the MySQL connector. To enable it, you need to make a change to your connection string and add the User Variables=True parameter.

Comment: Thanks again.  I'll post the full working query code in my question for future reference.